# Load image from file to dynamic resource programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, resources

I need to load an image file to WPF's dynamic resource programmatically because the directory which contains the image files can be moved.

How can I load an image to WPF's dynamic resource which is used like this: `Source="{DynamicResource ...}"` in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource MyDynamicImage}" />
```

In code:

```cs
var myimg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("SomeUriHere"));
Resources["MyDynamicImage"] = myimg;
```

(The `Resources` collection should be one which is in the scope of the `Image` of course, if you have a direct reference to the `Image` control you can also use the immediate `Image.Resources`)

Whenever you set a new object to that resource key the `DynamicResource` will update.